# Are characters unlocked by number of individual track races completed?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

When trying to unlock characters,  is the amount of races needed the amount of individual tracks or the amount of complete versus races  (say you do 4-track races,  does that set of 4 count as 4 or 1 toward the total?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A race is one single track.

A group of four races on four different tracks is a cup.

For unlocking characters via the racing criteria, finishing a four track cup would count as four individual races.